# Use clevercloud drain with Elasticsearch target

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

I'm using Clevercloud to host my application and I want to store logs in an Elasticsearch index. I read the documentation [here](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-tools/lifecycle/#get-continuous-logs-from-your-application) and I tried to create a drain as explained. I was able to create the drain but no data has been added in my Elasticsearch.

Somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : I couldn't see datas because I was looking at the wrong ES index. Even if you specified an index in your URL, logs are in logstash format so by default it will create a new index per day named `logstash-YYYY-MM-DD`. The datas was in those indexes.